# What to do when you have a list of value in your dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary in which the value is a list.
Example:

```
dict={1:[2,3],2:[5,6]}
```

I want the following output:

`a  b
 1  2
 2  5
 2  6`

How do I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its better to give your code what you have attempted and the issues that you are facing with your approach.

Comment: What happened to `1 3`?

Answer (score 0):

This will do. All you need to do is format it as you please.

```
for key,value in dict.items():
    print(key)
    for n in value:
        print(n)
```

The output is as follows:
`1 2 3 2 5 6`

Answer (score 0):

I think your last pair is `3 6` instead of `2 6`, we all do mistakes, in this case you can do :

```
my_dict = {1:[2,3],2:[5,6]}

print('a', 'b')
print(*(' '.join(map(str, e)) for e in zip(*((k, *v) for k, v in my_dict.items()))),sep='\n')
```

output:

```
a b
1 2
2 5
3 6
```